# Python, Pandas: How to automatically skip Excel header cells and add the rest to a dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Greetings I would like to transform an excel document into a dataframe, but unfortunately the excel documents are made by someone else and they will always headers like so:

[Excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUQsv.png)

I would like to ignore the "made by stevens" and "made 04/02/21" parts and just read the relevant information like name, age, file.

1. How would I skip it using pandas
2. Is there a way to always skip those header information, even if the relevant info (name, age, file) starts at a different line on different documents? (IE in one document age is at row 4 and in another age is at row 7)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function [`pandas.read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) has a parameter called `skiprows`, if you feed it an integer it will simply skip the n first lines at the start of the file.

In your case just use:

```py
df = pd.read_excel(filepath, skiprows=4)
```

The second part of your question this is trickier. Depending on your business use cases you might have different solutions. If the columns are always the same (`Name`, `Age`, `file`) you could import the excel file without skipping lines but with fixing the column names, then by dropping rows with empty data and the additional header row you didn't use.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to skip header which is on row = 1, then you can try this

```
pandas.read_excel(skiprows=1, skipfooter=0)
```

you can specify the value in integer to skiprows=1 to skip header and skipfooter=1 to skip footer, the number can depending upon how many rows you want to skip.